# How to let htop display all columns correctly when using the Homebrew Terminal profile?

Tags: terminal, color

I've installed `htop` with :

```
brew install htop
```

But when I run it with `sudo htop`, the user column is not fully displayed. Some parts are missing.

How to display it correctly?

P.S.: I'm using the Homebrew Terminal profile.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the menu `Terminal -> Preferences... -> Profiles -> Text`

and select `Use bright color for bold text`

Now you can see everything.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to replicate this behaviour, but could not see that "the user column is not fully displayed". Are you saying that you're just getting black text on a black background (which the "Homebrew" profile would have)?

Comment: Yes, exactly black on black and when I move the selection bar on a line, I can read again the text. I'm using Terminal 2.6.1 (361.1)